# Javascript Ajax loader gif doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax loader gif with XMLHttpRequest.

if i type somthing in the input, i see a list with different words it's the technique you often see in search engines when you are typing something in the searchbox. but i also see the Ajax loader and it keeps loading even if i delete the text. That is not what i want.

What have i done wrong?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input"  />

    <div id='loading' style='display: none'><img src="gifs/ajax-loader.gif" title="Loading" /></div>

    <div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {

    var loader = document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "ajaxtest.php?data=" + input.value, true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            //loader.src = "gifs/ajax-loader.gif";

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = request.responseText;

        }
        if (document.getElementById("input").value === "") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";

        }
    };
    loader.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: You're never checking to see if input is empty, only that it had a keyup

Answer (score 0):

first add a event for better input value retrieving:

```
input.addEventListener("keyup change", function () {
```

You may use little jQuery code:

```
$("#loading").hide();
........
if (request.readyState === 4) {
//replace loader.src = "gifs/ajax-loader.gif"; with...
                $("#loading").show();

                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = request.responseText;

            }
            if (document.getElementById("#input").value === "") {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
           //new code
               $("#loading").hide();
            }
        };
      //replace  loader.style.display = "none"; with ...
        $("#loading").hide();  
    });
```

Comment: can't this be done without jQuery? I tried to make it without it.